# Is there a way to check the body of a Node.js https request before I send it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to debug some API calls, and I want to confirm that I'm sending what I think I'm sending.

```
var req = https.request(request, function(res) {
  var body;
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  body = "";
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    return body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
      return settings.success(null, JSON.parse(body), res);
    } else {
      return settings.error(body, null, res);
    }
  });
  return res.on('error', function() {
    return settings.error(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments), res);
  });
});
if (settings.data != null) {
  req.write(settings.data);
}
// check body of req here
```

`settings.data` is a protobuf buffer. I want to check the final written body because there is a bug somewhere in the call and I would like to see exactly what I am sending. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can write the buffer all up in memory first (keep appending to a variable), then send it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the original question. To check what you're *sending*, you can use `util.inspect(settings.data)` to return a string that displays the contents of that variable *or* use `console.dir(settings.data)` to display that string implicitly to stdout (`console.dir()` uses `util.inspect()` behind the scenes).

**Original answer:**

I believe that protocol buffers are *binary*, however you're converting all of the data to a utf8 string. You might try keeping it all as binary:

```
var body = [], nb = 0;
res.on('data', function(chunk) {
  body.push(chunk);
  nb += chunk.length;
});
res.on('end', function() {
  body = Buffer.concat(body, nb);
  // now `body` contains all protocol buffer data in the original binary format
});
```

If you then want to get a textual representation of what's in the buffer, you could use `util.inspect()`. For example:

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;

// ...

res.on('end', function() {
  body = Buffer.concat(body, nb);
  if (res.statusCode === 200)
    settings.success(null, inspect(body), res);
  else
    settings.error(body, null, res);
});
```

Comment: Interesting point about the utf8 encoding. Should I assume that `res` is actually `req` or do I misunderstand your code?

Comment: So far as I can tell, this only helps me look at **what I got back** rather than **what I am sending**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah I see now, I misunderstood your question. To check what you're sending, you can use the same `util.inspect()` on `settings.data` or `console.dir(settings.data)` if you want to log that to stdout.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that would check what's **actually** in the request, it would only check what I passed as the argument to req.write(). Right? If something went wrong with the call, then that method wouldn't help figure that out.

Comment: Nothing can "go wrong" with `req.write()`. The data is passed through as-is. If you're still really *that* concerned, you can always use tcpdump/wireshark/etc..